# using asynctask to send email

Tags: java, android-asynctask, jakarta-mail

The issue: When this code is run without AsyncTask, there is an error, when run in an AsyncTask, nothing seems to happen (as in no email is sent)

strange thing is, when i run the same code through eclipse, the email is sent. I tested on bluestacks2 and droid4x emulators.

the code:

```
     new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... Void) {

                        String to = "toemail";


                        String from = "fromemail";
                        final String username = "username";//change accordingly
                        final String password = "password";//change accordingly


                        String host = "localhost";

                        Properties props = new Properties();
                        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
                        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
                        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
                        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");


                        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                                    }
                                });

                        try {

                            // Create a default MimeMessage object.
                            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

                            // Set From: header field of the header.
                            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

                            // Set To: header field of the header.
                            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                                    InternetAddress.parse(to));

                            // Set Subject: header field
                            message.setSubject("TEST SUBJECT");

                            // Now set the actual message
                            message.setText("TEST BODY");

                            // Send message
                            Transport.send(message);


                        } catch (MessagingException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                }.execute();
```

Comment: Are you sure this code is ever being called?  What does the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show?

Comment: @BillShannon hey, yes the code is definitely called. I fixed the problem by changing my "host" from localhost. Thanks!